# Appmaker: How can I create and access global variables?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I am trying to make a button which acts as a switch, enabling the visibility of a panel.
I am running a client side script when the onClick event fires, which is the following:

```
function {
  if(app.datasources.global.item.hideshow===false)
    {
       *does one thing*
    }
    else if(app.datasources.global.item.hideshow===true)
    { 
       *does another*
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the global (which is the datasource).item seems to be a null according to the console error log. It seems like i am trying to access one property of a record from a database, but I would like to access and edit a property which is not attached to any database, it would be just a "global variable".

Maybe I haven't phrased it too well, but I hope somebody can help me out with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would seem that your datasource 'global' is most likely not loaded client side. Even if you set your datasource to 'auto load' that does not mean that the datasource will actually get loaded, it only means that it will automatically load when a page or other element is set to the datasource that it will just load by itself, but you still need something in your app that actually loads this datasource. I would suggest loading this datasource in your app startup script or maybe instead of using a global var inside a datasource just use page properties instead.

Comment: Another thing to consider, when using a datasource for something simple like a global variable, you are then needing to make DB calls to update that variable. Since there is lag in doing this your UI would possibly become sluggish. As was already suggested I would use the custom properties for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this.  This link may help [ontoggle Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_ontoggle_dom).
Another way I could see doing this would be using local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custom property](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#custom_properties) for that. So in the page where you want to toggle the panel, create a custom property and perhaps call it **panelVisibility**. Then you can use the following logic on the onclick event handler of the button:

```
var visible = widget.root.properties.panelVisibility || false;
if(visible){
  //do someting
} else {
  //do other thing
}
widget.root.properties.panelVisiblity = !visible;
```