# Google AppMaker how to define App level variables

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there any way of defining app level variables that are accessible by any client side script?

Edit:
So this was suggested that it's a possible duplicate. What I am asking is not a page wide variable, those can be done in properties with different types and a dynamic type, what I am asking is a client side app level variables that can be accessed by any client side script or the functions that go into the predefined functions of the widgets.

For example, if I want to count the number of clicks done by a user on all pages (say just only the buttons), how do I do it? If I create a database for the count, it will be across all opened sessions which is not what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appmaker: How can I create and access global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101720/appmaker-how-can-i-create-and-access-global-variables)

Comment: @Morfinismo, no it doesn't answer the question, that is page level, I want App level, so that the variable is shared between pages. Also if a database is used for it, then it wouldn't be session based, the variable would be shared for all opened sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I see your point. The approach I'm using in cases like yours is that I put something like this in any script:

```
var $appVars = {
  name: "Tester",
  age: 26,
  height: "178cms",
  color: "purple",
  status: "pending"
};
```

Then I simply call them by using `$appVars.name` or `$appVars.color`. The only thing to take into account is that if you put this in a client script, it will only work with the client api. If you put this on a server script, it will only work with the server api. However, what I like about this is that the autocomplete feature takes it into account, which is great!

To update the value of the globals you simply do:

```
$appVars.name = "Another Tester;
$appVars.age = 29;
$appVars.status = "Complete";
```

And so forth, you get the idea.

Comment: I put the definition of $appVars in the onAppStart script but could not access it from another page, not sure if I missed something. My solution to all of this is to designate a page (or rather a page fragment like the header) to hold all global variables, since any page can access the data of any other page, I only recently realized this. The variable can be initialized in the onAppStart script.

Comment: @AsHal I did not test that in the appStartup script. Anyways... Glad you found a solution.